# Geumjeongsan Mountain walkable?

Tags: hiking, south-korea

I'm planning a trip to Busan, Korea and I wanted to check some temples by walking to them. A couple of places mention Geumjeongsan Mountain but it doesn't say much about an official hiking path. I wouldn't mind walking along the road but does anyone have an idea?

Comment: See also [Outdoors.SE] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/ATR/SI_EN_3_1_1_1.jsp?cid=1751500) mentions a few hiking trails around Geumjeongsan including some which include temples:

- Course 1 (8 km, 3 hr 30 min) Busan Nat'l Univ. - Gobyeoldae Cliffs - Dongmun Gate - Buchaebawi Rocks - Bungmun Gate - Geumjeongsan Mountain
- Course 2 (7 km, 2 hr) Dongnae - Mandeokgogae Hill - Seokbulsa Temple - Sanggyebong Peak
- Course 3 (6 km, 2 hr) Geumgang Park - Nammun Gate - Sanggyebong Peak
- Course 4 (6 km, 2 hr) Busan Nat'l Univ. - Dongmun Gate - Sanggyebong Peak
- Course 5 (6.5 km) Beomeosa Temple - Bungmun Gate - Dongmun Gate
- Course 6 Botanical Garden - Dongmun Gate - Bungmun Gate - Beomeosa Temple
- Course 7 (8 km, 2 hr 40 min) Jung-ri (Sanseongmaeul) - Gukcheongsa Temple - Bungmun Gate - Godangbong Peak

Comment: Ah this is exactly what I was looking for thanks! I either bad at looking in the right places or that site is hard to navigate.